# Suggestions for returning memory from a class

Tags: c++, opengl, cpp-core-guidelines

I have a class which is supposed to keep pixel data (floats for the position, floats for the color). I'm trying to use a C++ style in data members (the data is kept in `std::array<float, N>` instead of plain C arrays). The class has other getters, setters and functions meant to be "helpers" to populate these fields.

Now I need to create an OpenGL vertex data buffer where I should write out

```
  4 floats for xyzw
  4 floats for rgba
  2 floats for UV coords
```

in this order. I'm wondering how should I do this.. I tried doing

```
class MyVertexData {
  std::array<float, 4> pos;
  std::array<float, 4> rgba;
  std::array<float, 2> uv;
public:
  void writeData(float *ptrToMemory) {
    if(ptrToMemory == nullptr)
      throw std::runtime_exception("Null pointer");

    std::array<float, 10> output;

    output= {
      pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], pos[3],
      rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3],
      uv[0], uv[1]
    };

    memcpy(memory, out.data(), 10 * sizeof(float));
  }
};


// Caller code
std::vector<float[10]> buffer(4);
vertex0.writeElements(buffer[0]);
vertex1.writeElements(buffer[1]);
vertex2.writeElements(buffer[2]);
vertex3.writeElements(buffer[3]);
```

but this approach has two problems:

1. I need to trust the caller to have allocated memory to store 10 floats
2. No C++11+ signature, I just get a float pointer

I can't just return a `std::unique_ptr` since I need a contiguous memory area (`buffer`) where the elements are to be stored, but I also need a distinction between the different elements (that would also make the code more readable).

It would be nice to return a smart pointer or something similar whose memory I can easily "concatenate" to other elements so I can safely pass this stuff to OpenGL.

Comment: Have you considered using a `std::vector`? Also, I know that raw arrays are not copyable (and thus can't be returned from a function), but I'm not so sure about `std::array`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I thought of returning `std::array`s but they're container objects like `vector`s, and I should probably copy from their memory afterwards into the `buffer`

Comment: You want some `array_view`.

Comment: Jarod is probably right. `array_view` sounds good if it's what I think (a type-safe evolution of the C-way of interpreting data starting at an address as a certain type/class/struct/whatever).

Comment: @Dean: In my opinion, using `std::array`s for arrays of completely static size of 4 or 2 is a total waste of ressources, especially since using a flat memory layout would allow you to directly use an array (preferrably `std::vector`) of instances of your class as interleaved opengl vertex arrays, while your current approach requires an extra copy for each vertex.

Comment: @derhass How is a zero-overhead class (which `std::array` is) a waste of resources?

Comment: @derhass: His current approach requires an extra copy per-vertex *only* because that's how he choose to implement it. His class is standard layout, and by the rules of C++, it is layout compatible with an array of 10 floats. There's nothing about his code that would prevent him from just copying an array of MyVertexData directly into the buffer object.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I stand corrected then. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#S-gsl) introduces `span` which is a *view* of contiguous element, so you may use something like:

```
void writeData(gsl::span<float, 10> ptrToMemory)
```

to express the intend.